# rest api for fetching outlook notes

Tags: python, outlook, exchangewebservices, outlook-restapi

I want to fetch notes from Notes folder in office 365.

Does microsoft have support with rest API to access these user-created notes inside Notes folder.

I couldn't find any article about it nor it is listed in outlook mail rest API reference.

I have created Notes using office 365 client. You can find this Notes folder in the same hierarchy in inbox, Drafts, Sent items.

It’s not feasible to create or modify notes using OWA.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The REST API's won't work for what you trying because StickyNotes have a ItemClass of IPM.StickyNote and the REST API for Messages will only return items that have a class or subclass of IPM.Note. You will need to use EWS (SOAP) try https://pypi.org/project/exchangelib/

Comment: I tried fetching using https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/MailFolders/notes/messages call. It worked. But how can I restore this Notes folder back in the user'account. (I use ews managed api to post soap message back to user's account)

Comment: I had to hardcode this notes well-known folder name to fetch these notes..

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as announced on November 17, 2020 (https://developer.microsoft.com/graph/blogs/outlook-rest-api-v2-0-deprecation-notice/) version 2.0 of the Outlook REST API has been deprecated and will be fully decommissioned in November 2022.

They recommend Microsoft Graph API instead, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/compare-graph

Comment: And how do exactly access the stickY notes in the graph API?

Comment: They are part of your mail API, with a special item type

Answer (score 0):

Yes
API: (GET)

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/MailFolders/notes/messages

Use Access Token as bearer token when calling the API.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33417978)